# JqGrid Primary Key other than Id

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Can any Body tell me how to configure primary key in JqGrid. Since Jqgrid uses id as primary key But I am using fid as primary key.

**Example of Jqgrid:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>PHP jqGrid</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/ui.jqgrid.css" />

        <script src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Here we set a globally the altRows option
            //jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.defaults, { altRows:true });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                jQuery("#jsonmap").jqGrid({
                    url:'example.php?q=4',
                    datatype: "json",
                    colNames:['FId','Id', 'Colname', 'Index','width','Form Name','Fiel Name','Editable','Show','Extra Field'],
                    colModel:[
                        {name:'fid',index:'fid', width:55,size:10,editable:false},
                        {name:'id',index:'id', width:90,editable:true,size:5}, /*name : database field name*/
                        {name:'col_name',index:'col_name', width:100,editable:true},
                        {name:'ind_ex',index:'ind_ex', width:80, align:"right",editable:true},
                        {name:'width',index:'width', width:80, align:"right",editable:true},
                        {name:'form_name',index:'form_name', width:80, align:"right",editable:true},
                        {name:'field_name',index:'field_name', width:80,align:"right",editable:true},
                        {name:'editable',index:'editable', width:150, sortable:false,editable:true},
                        {name:'s_how',index:'s_how', width:150, sortable:false,editable:true},
                        {name:'extra_field',index:'extra_field', width:150, sortable:false,editable:true}
                 /*{name:'id',index:'id', width:55,editable:false,editoptions:{readonly:true,size:10}},
        {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:80,editable:true,editoptions:{size:10}},
        {name:'name',index:'name', width:90,editable:true,editoptions:{size:25}},
        {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:60, align:"right",editable:true,editoptions:{size:10}},
        {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:60, align:"right",editable:true,editoptions:{size:10}},
        {name:'total',index:'total', width:60,align:"right",editable:true,editoptions:{size:10}},
        {name:'closed',index:'closed',width:55,align:'center',editable:true,edittype:"checkbox",editoptions:{value:"Yes:No"}},
        {name:'ship_via',index:'ship_via',width:70, editable: true,edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:"FE:FedEx;TN:TNT"}},
        {name:'note',index:'note', width:100, sortable:false,editable: true,edittype:"textarea", editoptions:{rows:"2",cols:"20"}}
                   */ ],
                    rowNum:10,
                    rowList:[10,20,30],
                    pager: '#pjmap',
                    sortname: 'id',
                    viewrecords: true,
                    sortorder: "desc",
                    gridview: true,
                    editurl:'edit.php',
                    closeAfterEdit: true,
                    closeAfterAdd: true,
                   jsonReader: {
                  //     root: "Rows",
                //page: "Page",
                //total: "Total",
                //records: "Records",
                repeatitems: false,
                 **fid: "PrimaryKey"**
                        //repeatitems : false,
                        //id: "5"

                    },
                    caption: "ADD DELETE UPDATE",
                    height: '100%'
                }).navGrid('#pager',{edit:false,add:true,del:true,search:false}).navButtonAdd('#pjmap',{
                    caption:"Add",
                    buttonicon:"ui-icon-add",
                    closeAfterAdd:true,
                    onClickButton: function(){
                       jQuery("#jsonmap").editGridRow("new",{height:400,scroll:true,reloadAfterSubmit:false});
                        //alert("Adding Row");
                    },
                    position:"last"
                })

               /* .navButtonAdd('#pjmap',{

                    caption:"Del",
                    buttonicon:"ui-icon-del",
                    onClickButton: function(rp_ge,postdata){
                        alert(getRowData(postdata.id));

                    },
                    position:"last"
                });
                */
            });


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="jsonmap"></table>
        <div id="pjmap"></div>
<!--<input type="BUTTON" id="bedata" value="Edit Selected" />-->
    </body>
</html>

server2.php
<?php
include_once('../../../../wp-load.php');
include('dbconfig.php');
$page = $_GET['page']; // get the requested page 
$limit = $_GET['rows']; // get how many rows we want to have into the grid 
$sidx = $_GET['sidx']; // get index row - i.e. user click to sort 
$sord = $_GET['sord']; // get the direction 
if(!$sidx) $sidx =1; // connect to the database 
$result = @mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM $table");
$row = @mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC); 
$count = $row['count'];
if ( $count >0 ) 
   { $total_pages = ceil($count/1); } 
else
   { $total_pages = 0; } 
if ($page > $total_pages) 
  $page=$total_pages;
$start = $limit*$page - $limit; // do not put $limit*($page - 1) 
$SQL = "SELECT * from $table Order By id "; 
$SQL = "SELECT * from $table"; 
$result = @mysql_query( $SQL ) or die("Couldn t execute query.".mysql_error()); 
$responce->page = $page; $responce->total = $total_pages; $responce->records = $count; $i=0; 
while($row = @mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{ 
$responce->rows[$i]['id']=$row[id]; 
$responce->rows[$i]['cell']=array($row[id],$row[business_name],$row[title],$row[firstname],$row[lastname],$row[address],$row[city],$row[state],$row[postcode],$row[email]); 
$i++; 
} 
echo json_encode($responce);  
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can either use

```
jsonReader: {repeatitems: false, id: "fid" }
```

or use

```
jsonReader: {repeatitems: false }
```

and define additional `key:true` property for the 'fid' column definition:

```
{ name:'fid', index:'fid', key:true, width:55 }
```

The `key:true` property overwrite `id` property of `jsonReader`.

One more remark: If you want use `closeAfterEdit: true` and `closeAfterAdd: true` setings of form editing you should define there on another place: as a part of `navGrid` parameters:

```
jQuery("#jsonmap").jqGrid({
    // ... jqGrid parameters
}).navGrid('#pager',
           {/*navGrid options*/},
           {closeAfterEdit: true}, // Edit form options
           {closeAfterAdd: true}   // Add form options
           )
  .navButtonAdd('#pjmap',{
                // navButtonAdd options
            })
```

Comment: @user776022: What exactly you tried? Is your demo accessible from the internet so I could debug it?